# How to localize multiple NSDictionaries in plist using Localizable.strings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, plist, localizable.strings

I can localize the plist by having the localized version of `plist` i.e plist (english) and `plist` (french). I don't want to go this way. I want to use `Localizable.string` for all my `plists`.

In my plist file, I have 10 `NSDictionaries` with keys **name,message,number** and each `NSDictionary` in the `plist` has a key in the format **dict1,dict2...dict10.**

So this is how it looks in a plist

```
dict1      NSDictionary       (3 items)
   name          String           John
   message       String           How are you?
   number        String           10
```

Now, in my **Localizable.strings** ,

For a simple string I would write

```
 "simpleString"="Hello";
```

But how to write for more than 1 dictionary ?

If I write

```
  "message" = "How are you?";
```

then this would cause issue as I have 10 dictionaries with the key **message**.

How can I use the plist dictionary key **dict1,dict2....dict10** in **Localizable.strings** ?

I am looking for a solution something like:

```
"dict1"."title" ="something";
"dict2"."title"="somehtoing 2";
```

Comment: instead of storing the 'message' in dict, store a key as in 'something.messageKey', then localize 'something.messageKey' in your localizable strings ... for example. As L. Wall says, there is more than one way to do this.

Comment: It would be a pain process to do for large plists. If I didn't find any solution, I will go with yours. @YvesLeBorg